# Create a property called Ingredients

Tags: c#, list, class, oop

- Create a property called Ingredients.
- Create a GetCost method which calculates the total cost of the ingredients used to make the smoothie.
- Create a GetPrice method which returns the number from GetCost plus
  the number from GetCost multiplied by 1.5. Round to two decimal
  places.
- Create a GetName method which gets the ingredients and puts
  them in alphabetical order into a nice descriptive sentence. If there are multiple ingredients, add the word "Fusion" to the end but otherwise add "Smoothie". Remember to change "-berries" to "-berry"

..............................

i am stuck here ! can you help me with this !

.........................

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

namespace test
{
    class Smoothie
    {
        private string[] _ingredients;
        private double Cost;
        public Smoothie() { }
        public Smoothie(string[] p_ingredients)
        {
            this._ingredients = p_ingredients;
        }
        public string[] Ingredients
        {
            get { return this._ingredients; }
            set { this._ingredients = value; }
        }

        public double GetCost()
        {
            double Cost = 0;

            return this.Cost;
        }

        public string GetPrice()
        {
            return Convert.ToString(this.GetCost() * 2.5); 
        }

        public string GetName()
        {
            List<string> names = new List<string>();

            foreach (string name in this._ingredients)
            {
               
                    names.Add(name);
            }

            if (names.Count < 2)
            {
                names.Add("Smoothie");
            }
            else
            {
                names.Sort();
                names.Add("Fusion");
            }

            return string.Join(" ", names);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Smoothie smoothie = new Smoothie();
            List<string> names = new List<string>();

            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (userInput)
                {
                    case "Strawberries":
                        
                        names.Remove("Straw-berries");
                        names.Add("Straw-berry");
                    break;

                case "2":
                        if (names.Contains("Banana"))
                        {
                        }
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        if (names.Contains("Mango"))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Mango have already been added!");
                        }
                        break;
                 
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Which step in particular are you stuck on?

Comment: The code you've written is not idiomatic C#, it looks more like a Java program, just written in C#.

Comment: I am stuck is not a proper problem description. What exactly is the issue you are seeing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.